# Lead/Ball Finish on TI parts

Tags: integrated-circuit, texas-instruments, materials, lead-free

I will be using the TMP117 in a design I'm working on, and was a bit curious to what the difference is between the different Lead/Ball finishes listed in the datasheet?

There's a choice between NIPDAU and SAC396, and I havent been able to find much information on the advantages/disadvantages betweent the two. As far as I've gathered sofar it relates mostly to the shelf life of the components, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TMP117](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmp117.pdf) is available in 2 package styles:

1. WSON (a type of [DFN](https://eesemi.com/dfn.htm) package) and the pins have a NiPdAu finish (this is compatible with both SnPb and lead free processes).
2. WSBGA (a [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) package) which by definition will have solder balls and the solder balls are [SAC396](http://www.almit.com/dloads/Agents/SAC%20Alloy%20Comparison.pdf) which is a type of lead free solder.

There is not really any confusion; BGA devices will always have solder balls whereas other types of package rarely have any solder finish.

Answer (score 1):

[SAC](http://www.almit.com/dloads/Agents/SAC%20Alloy%20Comparison.pdf)396 is a solder type, NiPdAu (Nickel-Palladium-Gold) is a surface finish, typically.

So, bit of a different category.

TI has a [document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza031/szza031.pdf) on its NiPdAu contact finish's potential for solder embrittlement. Maybe that's of interest to you?